# java: Convert Location into String and back

Tags: android, location, android-room, typeconverter

For android Room, i need a type converter to save Location objects. Converting Locations to String is rather simple, e.g.:

```
public static String locationStringFromLocation(final Location location) {
        if (location==null) return "Location was null";
        return Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES) + " " + Location.convert(location.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
    }
```

But the other way around seems less obvious. I could append all the properties and separate them with a delimiter, but that seems not quite elegant. Any ideas would be appreciated.

My current workaround is to just save latitude and longitude, but I'd prefer to have the object.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Location locationFromString(String location){
    if (location != null && (location.contains(","))) {
        Location result = new Location("Generated_location");
        String[] locationStrings = location.split(",");
        if (locationStrings.length == 2) {
            result.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(locationStrings[0]));
            result.setLongitude((Double.parseDouble(locationStrings[1])));
            return result;
        } else { return null; }
    } else  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static Location parseLocationString(String locString){
    if(locString != null && locString.contains("Location")) {
        Location location = new Location("");
        String rep = locString.replace("Location", "")
                .replace("[", "")
                .replace("]", "");
        String[] k = rep.split(" ");

        for (int part = 0; part < k.length; part++) {
            String string = k[part];
            if(part == 0)location.setProvider(string);
            else if (part == 1){
                String[] latlng = string.split(",");
                if(latlng.length > 1){
                    location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latlng[0]));
                    location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(latlng[1]));
                }
            }
            else if (part > 1){
                String[] locationDetails = string.split("=");
                if (locationDetails.length > 1){
                    String locationKey = locationDetails[0];
                    String locationValue = locationDetails[1];

                    if (locationKey.contains("hAcc")) {
                        if (!locationValue.contains("?"))
                            location.setAccuracy((float)Float.parseFloat(locationValue));
                    }else if (locationKey.contains("et")){
                        if( !locationValue.contains("?") )
                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                                if(locationValue.contains("+")) {
                                    long days = 0, hours, min, sec, mill;
                                    //separate string value
                                    String nmbr = locationValue.split("\\+")[1];
                                    String[] hr;
                                    //isolate each value
                                    String[] d = nmbr.split("d");
                                    if(d.length > 1){
                                        days = Long.parseLong(d[0]);
                                    }
                                    if(d.length > 1)
                                        hr = d[1].split("h");
                                    else
                                        hr = nmbr.split("h");
                                    if(hr.length > 1) {
                                        hours = Long.parseLong(hr[0]);
                                    }else hours = 0;
                                    if(days > 0)
                                        hours += 24*days;

                                    String[] m;
                                    if(hr.length > 1)
                                        m = hr[1].split("m");
                                    else
                                        m = hr[0].split("m");
                                    if(m.length > 1) {
                                        if(m[0].length() > 0)
                                            try {
                                                min = Long.parseLong(m[0]);
                                            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                                                min = 0;
                                            }
                                        else min = 0;
                                    } else min= 0;

                                    String[] s = m[0].split("s");
                                    if(s.length > 1) {
                                        sec = Long.parseLong(s[0]);
                                    }else sec = 0;

                                    if(min != 0 || hours != 0) {
                                        String[] ms = s[0].split("ms");
                                        if (ms.length >= 0 && !ms[0].contains("s")) {
                                            mill = Long.parseLong(ms[0]);
                                        } else mill = 0;
                                    }else{
                                        String ms = s[1];
                                        if (ms.length() >= 0 && !ms.contains("s")) {
                                            mill = Long.parseLong(ms);
                                        } else mill = 0;
                                    }
                                    long millInNano = 1000000;
                                    long nano = mill * millInNano;
                                    nano += (sec * 1000) * millInNano;
                                    nano += ((min * 60) * 1000) * millInNano;
                                    nano += (((hours * 60) * 60) * 1000) * millInNano;

                                    location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(nano);
                                }
                            }
                    }else if (locationKey.contains("vel")) {
                        if (!locationValue.contains("?"))
                            location.setSpeed(Float.parseFloat(locationValue));
                    }else if (locationKey.contains("vAcc")) {
                        if (!locationValue.contains("?"))
                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
                                location.setVerticalAccuracyMeters(Float.parseFloat(locationValue));
                    }else if (locationKey.contains("sAcc")) {
                        if (!locationValue.contains("?"))
                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
                                location.setSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond(Float.parseFloat(locationValue));
                    }else if (locationKey.contains("bAcc")) {
                        if (!locationValue.contains("?"))
                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
                                location.setBearingAccuracyDegrees(Float.parseFloat(locationValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return location;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```